# hMailServer only replies on first time

Tags: windows, email, smtp, mx-record, hmail-server

I've just installed hmail on Windows 2012 to self host a mail server.  Opened the ports (25, 143 - SMTP, IMAP).  Setup auto reply on some test accounts on domain.

I have a strange experience:  The first emails I send to the new inboxes from my gmail account get auto-replied.  Thereafter any more emails sent are largely not replied (i.e. mostly not replied but occassionaly very late).  The hMailServer logs show it found the emails and sending the replies.  I tried with my work email account to the new hMailServer inboxes and its the same situation.

I've checked the spam and they only occasionally go in there depending on the auto reply message body.  Reverse DNS has been setup by my cloud instance provider.

Not sure whats going on but the hMailServer diagnosis does show red lights against MX records not being found local and internet domains (although internet MX route checking sites give it a green light when checking).

Why is it only sending out first time and then less likely other times.

Answer (score 1):

Ok its because the autoreply function only sends auto replies once per email address.  I ended up applying a 'rule' instead to reply and delete the incoming the message to reach the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The autoreply feature only ONCE per email address PER SESSION.  That is to say, when hmailserver (service) is stopped and restarted the cache is cleared and so the first occurrence of the autoreply already sent is forgotten.  (Note: it also doesnt autoreply to 'auto-reply' emails as this could cause looping)